# Understanding Graphite and how it works?

Tags: python, graphite, statsd

I am planning to use Graphite to monitor various services. I am trying to understand the architecture of how Graphite works. below is my understanding:

1. Whisper : This stores data into database in the form of time series. Database can be any example sqlite, Mysql Db2 etc ?
2. Carbon: Listens to metric data which then sends to whisper to save in the database ? So does this mean i can write a program in any programming language to send metric data to carbon ? What all parameter do i need in-order to connect to carbon and send data ?
3. Graphite-webapp: Does  Graphite-webapp reads the time series data stored in the database by whisper ? Will it create the graph/charts by itself ? Or do we need to program in python to display graph ? How do we create the KPI dashboard that will display the charts ?

All i did was read through the documentation, can someone help me understand the architecture of Graphite ? What all tools/framework can i use ? I am more of a Java/PHP/NODEJS dev thus trying to avoid python as much as possible:),
 tutorial or sample example would be perfect.

I have data in the format below saved  as a flat file that i need to send to graphite in order to display charts.

```
DATE TIME  Col1 Col2
2014-07-04 04:05:10  499 303
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for my poor English.

A great article about [graphite architecture](http://www.aosabook.org/en/graphite.html)

And I have used graphite to monitor spider cluster. Below is the some point you mentioned.

1. sqlite, Mysql, postgresql is OK. I don't know DB2, Because few people use django and DB2 together (Graphite-webapp is a django app).
2. I think you can write a program in any programming language to send metric data to carbon. Because you send data to carbon  by TCP  connection.
3. Graphite-webapp is a django project. Almost all you need to do , is install it, May be   some python work about settings.

By the way, The [official documents](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is great.